# jquery and pathname ... again ! ;-)

Tags: substring, pathname

I'm trying the slug of my url at the end.

If url is one of the followings, I want to get "link1" only (no quotes).

http://www.site.com/link1

http://www.site.com/category/link1

http://www.site.com/myblog/category/link1

This is what I have but only the 2 firsts work.

```
$(".ajaxed").live("click", function(event) {
        var post_slug = $(this)[0].pathname.substring($(this)[0].pathname.lastIndexOf("/")).replace(/^\//, "");
        alert(post_slug);
        $.address.crawlable(true).value(post_slug);
        $(this).load("ajax/",{slug:post_slug}, function(){
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Can I get help with the syntax please? Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: All those should work the same according to your code. You probably just had a trailing slash in your last url when you were testing it. site.com/myblog/category/link1*/*

Comment: Damn you're right! ;-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just split the string and return the very end?

```
var post_slug_array = $(this)[0].pathname.split('/');
var post_slug = post_slug_array[post_slug_array.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've try run:

```
t = "http://www.site.com/myblog/category/link1";
t.substring(t.lastIndexOf("/")).replace(/^\//,"");
console.log(t);
```

and I got `link1`. It's right, isn't it? so what's the problem on earth?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are after, but trim the trailing slash. How do you want to handle querystrings? Your current code includes them.

http://jsfiddle.net/ppyJr/1/

```
//test cases
var paths = new Array(
    'http://www.site.com/link1', 
    'http://www.site.com/myblog/category/link1',
    'http://www.site.com/myblog/category/link1?querystring', 
    'http://www.site.com/myblog/category/link1/',
    'http://www.site.com/myblog/category/link1/?querystring'
);

for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    //trim trailing slash
    var x = paths[i].replace(/\/$/, "");
    //get trailing item
    var post_slug = x.substring(x.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, x.length);
    alert(post_slug);   
}
```

Comment: I updated my question. I use AJAX to load content on my home page. It works for the first two links but not the 3rd. That's the problem.

Comment: Your code does work. So the value you are getting back for pathname is not what you think it is, or it has a trailing slash. http://jsfiddle.net/tKJes/.